# CSS Height and Width attributes not working correctly in IE10

Tags: css, image, web, height, width

(Prior to this issue, I used conditional IE statements to make part of this excluded from IE Browsers, but that is no longer supported in IE10.)

So I have three images on the header of my site stacked on top of each other. The one on the bottom is a .gif with a moving arm, the one above that is an image identical to the .gif but without the arm at all and in higher resolution (as the .gif cannot support a similar image quality.) On the same layer as the hi-res pick, I have a hi-res image of just the arm. I have the css set up so that when the image is hovered over, the only-arm image disappears revealing the .gif with the moving arm.

You can view this here: http://www.applocity.blogspot.com
(If viewed in Chrome or Firefox, it will work correctly. If viewed in IE prior to 10, only the gif will show without the hover-over animation, and if viewed in IE10 it will show the solo-arm no lined up correctly with the background image (although the animation works)

I believe the problem lies in this code:

```
#chicken {
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

#chicken:hover {
opacity:0;
}
```

This is the CSS code for the solo-arm and on Chrome and FF, the width and height 100% attributes work correctly and the arm aligns itself with the background, but in IE, it doesn't work for some reason.

Can someone please tell me to either make the arm align with the image, or remove it only in IE using a method working for IE10?

Comment: Hi there! Why do you need the animation to work like this? Why not just have two images, and change them on hover using JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to fix the issue by adding `text-align: center` to `#chicken` as below:

```
#chicken {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center; /* add this */
}
```

Another way you can do it is by adding this rule:

```
#chicken a{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```